# Extracting from webpage using vbs and writing into excel

Tags: html, excel, web, properties, vbscript

I'm pretty new to VBS but I need to extract property information from web pages and input the information into excel. What I'm trying to do is get is object information from links, text fields, buttons, images etc. The information I need is the .name, .id, .title, .value, .type, .class for each item on the page and display it together for each item ie: from the google search page the search box is .id:  lst-ib, .name:  q .title:  Search .type:  text  Then the Google Button is .name:  btnK .type:  submit .value:  Google Search etc etc. Any help would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I advise another language for such purpose, eg Ruby is very good at it and a natural upstep for VbScripters.
That said, here is a way how to do it in VbScript..

```
set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
with IE
  .MenuBar = 0
  .ToolBar = 0
  .StatusBar = 0
  .Visible = 1
  .navigate "http://www.google.com"
end with
while IE.busy
  wScript.sleep 400
wend

'html = IE.document.all.tags("html").item(0).outerhtml
wscript.echo IE.document.getElementsByTagName("font").item(0).innerText 
wscript.echo "innerText:" & IE.document.all.tags("title").item(0).innerText
wscript.echo "innerHtml:" & IE.document.all.tags("title").item(0).innerHtml
wscript.echo "outerHtml:" & IE.document.all.tags("title").item(0).outerHtml
IE.quit

'gives
'Google.be aangeboden in: français Deutsch English
'innerText:Google
'innerHtml:Google
'outerHtml:<title>Google</title>
```